# Django - Upload a file and populate field model with file name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `Django` and want to build an upload file page. When user upload a file, it stores it in a folder. I wan't to get the original file name to populate a field in my model (`SourceFile.file`).

File is well uploaded, but I can't reach `request.FILES` properties, even with `request.FILES.get('uploaded_to')` or `request.FILES['uploaded_to']` to fill in `SourceFile.file` with file name.

How to achieve this ? My source is [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model).

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class SourceFile(models.Model):
    file = models.CharField()
    uploaded_to = models.FileField(upload_to ='/uploads/')
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class SourceFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SourceFile
        fields = ['file', 'uploaded_to']
```

**views.py**

```
class SourceFileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SourceFileSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        return Response("GET API")        
    
    def upload_file(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = SourceFile(request.POST, request.FILES)
            # Nothing happened
            file_uploaded = request.FILES.get('uploaded_to')            
            file_name = file_uploaded.name
            request.POST['file'] = file_name
            #
            if form.is_valid():              
                form.save()                     
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/success/url/")                
            else:
                form = SourceFile()
            return render(request, "upload.html", {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to store the file name seperately, you can access it directly by:

```
instance = SourceFile.objects.first()
print(instance.uploaded_to.name)
```

More information can be found in the [documenation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/files/).

Comment: Ok, and how to insert this in the `POST` method for a specific field ? I tried `request.POST['file']`, but nothing happened.

Comment: This method ‘upload_file’ will not be called because it is not part of viewset class

Answer (score 0):

As @ruddra suggests my method with a form is not a part of viewset class. A better way is:

```
class upload_file(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.SourceFile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SourceFileSerializer
```